# Check all check boxes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I'm new in AngularJS. Please have look to this:

[image]

Now when user clicks on "All" link, all the **11 check boxes** should be checked and when user clicks on "None" link, all the **11 check boxes** should be unchecked.

Plus when user check the **All others** check box, all the bottom **9 check boxes** should be checked and when user uncheck the **All others** check box, all the bottom **9 check boxes** should be unchecked.

I'm able to achieve one of the task at a time, but not simultaneously.
So, can anybody please help me to achieve both the tasks simultaneously?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would be good if anyone can give me plucker or jsfiddle demo which has with my exact functionality i.e both ways to check checkboxes

Comment: It would be even better if you can share your attempt to achieve it!

Comment: Here inly 9 check box's . where is another two check boxes? and also please send your code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="selectAll()">Select All</button>
    <button ng-click="clearAll()">Clear All</button>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="select" ng-click="checkAll()" />
    <br />

    <p>Checkboxes</p>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="c in checkbox" ng-model="checkbox[$index].selected">
</body>
```

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkbox = [
    {
      selected: false
    },
    {
      selected: false
    },
    {
      selected: false
    }
  ];
  // Check/uncheck all boxes
  $scope.selectAll = function () {
    $scope.select = true;
    angular.forEach($scope.checkbox, function (obj) {
        obj.selected = true;
    });
  };

  $scope.clearAll = function () {
    $scope.select = false;
    angular.forEach($scope.checkbox, function (obj) {
        obj.selected = false;
    });
  };

  $scope.checkAll = function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.checkbox, function (obj) {
        obj.selected = $scope.select;
    });
  };
});
```

Refer [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/PswfSWTQYnCDQvaHKJkB?p=preview)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer and detailed explanation with code. The only problem is now that my check box is inside a accordion that make issue with  your solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604689/issue-in-angular-bootstrap-directive-while-trying-to-access-scope

Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Sahil Gupta, there is an issue in your updated fiddle: First check main check box (beside the clear all button), then uncheck any 2-3 check boxes from the bottom check box row, now click on select all, it won't check those check boxes which you just have unchecked. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @ParthVora : Yeah this is a issue because as per angular doc "ng-checked" directive should not be used together with "ngModel". This is because ng-checked is expecting an expression, so by saying ng-checked="true", it is saying that the checkbox will always be checked by default.

Comment: I misunderstood the same . Removing the updated answer. Sorry for the same. The best way to do is to use the first solution.

Answer (score 2):

Html

```
 <button ng-click="selectAll()"> all</button>
 <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[item.id]">
  </div>
```

JQuery

```
$scope.selected = {};
$scope.selectAll= function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
    var item = $scope.items[i];
    $scope.selected[item.id] = true;
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-Checked`
Its makes you easier

refer [ng-Checked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

Comment: ng-checked just sets a boolean rather than setting the value of the ng-model

Answer (score 0):

```
<md-checkbox ng-click="checked = !checked; check = {}"></md-checkbox>
<div ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <md-checkbox ng-checked="checked || check[item]" ng-click="check[item] = !check[item]" ng-model="sel[item]"></md-checkbox>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64981318/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.