# Issue in angular-bootstrap directive while trying to access scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-bootstrap

I have used https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap for accordion, but with this directive I'm having scope issues. It only allows to use scope if ngController is declared inside of accordion.

Please visit below two Plunker links and you will understand what I'm trying to say:

**Example 1**: http://plnkr.co/edit/Fb4UauWWmHOnTyjMPFBo

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>  
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <accordion>
      <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
        <accordion-heading>
          Accordian - Click me <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="select" ng-click="checkAll()" /> Check me
        </div>
      </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
    alert($scope.select);
  };
});
```

**Example 2**: http://plnkr.co/edit/ljEMUnTqPBqUyub5eEB7

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <accordion>
    <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
      <accordion-heading>
        Accordian - Click me <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
      </accordion-heading>
      <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="select" ng-click="checkAll()" /> Check me
      </div>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
    alert($scope.select);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

We can pass the value from the function itself, not necessary to access value using $scope.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/fZZrDN4e8kbvimR2Wzya

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <accordion>
      <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
        <accordion-heading>
          Accordian - Click me <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="select" ng-click="checkAll(select)" /> Check me
        </div>
      </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkAll = function (select) {
    alert(select);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `scope` of `directive` "`accordionGroup`" in **Angular Bootstrap** is `isolated` and the `$scope` of `controller` "`AccordionDemoCtrl`" is inherited using `require` in a "`directive`".

So, for **Example1** when you try to access the `$scope` binding of `AccordionDemoCtrl`inside the `accordian group` `directive`, it is easily accessible. But as the `select` is in `local` `scope` of `accordian group` `directive` it is not accessible in the controller.

So, for **Example2** when you try to access the `$scope` binding of `AccordionDemoCtrl`inside the `accordian group directive` it is easily accessible as the controller is in the local `scope` for the `accordian group`.

Please refer [directive to directive Comm](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2015/03/25/communication-between-collaborating-directives-in-angular/).

This is code from the **Angular Bootstrap Library for  Accordian**

```
.directive('accordion', function () {
  return {
    restrict:'EA',
    controller:'AccordionController',
    transclude: true,
    replace: false,
    templateUrl: 'template/accordion/accordion.html'
  };
})

// The accordion-group directive indicates a block of html that will expand and collapse in an accordion
.directive('accordionGroup', function() {
  return {
    require:'^accordion',         // We need this directive to be inside an accordion
    restrict:'EA',
    transclude:true,              // It transcludes the contents of the directive into the template
    replace: true,                // The element containing the directive will be replaced with the template
    templateUrl:'template/accordion/accordion-group.html',
    scope: {
      heading: '@',               // Interpolate the heading attribute onto this scope
      isOpen: '=?',
      isDisabled: '=?'
    },
    controller: function() {
      this.setHeading = function(element) {
        this.heading = element;
      };
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, accordionCtrl) {
      accordionCtrl.addGroup(scope);

      scope.$watch('isOpen', function(value) {
        if ( value ) {
          accordionCtrl.closeOthers(scope);
        }
      });

      scope.toggleOpen = function() {
        if ( !scope.isDisabled ) {
          scope.isOpen = !scope.isOpen;
        }
      };
    }
  };
})

// Use accordion-heading below an accordion-group to provide a heading containing HTML
// <accordion-group>
//   <accordion-heading>Heading containing HTML - <img src="..."></accordion-heading>
// </accordion-group>
.directive('accordionHeading', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,   // Grab the contents to be used as the heading
    template: '',       // In effect remove this element!
    replace: true,
    require: '^accordionGroup',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, accordionGroupCtrl, transclude) {
      // Pass the heading to the accordion-group controller
      // so that it can be transcluded into the right place in the template
      // [The second parameter to transclude causes the elements to be cloned so that they work in ng-repeat]
      accordionGroupCtrl.setHeading(transclude(scope, function() {}));
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Sahilgupta, I have read the link you referred, but still I don't get any solution here. Is that to much difficult to achieve? Should I change the directive which I have used for accordion?